# Do @media queries still work on links when also using a:hover, a:visited, etc

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, media-queries

I have a stylesheet using both @media queries and a:hover, a:visited, etc. in one element and it isn't working. The @media queries apply but the CSS from a:hover and a:visited doesn't work. I'm wondering if these elements can't work together or if there is an error in my code.

Here is my code:

```
#button {
     background-color: #003794;
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.9em;
     color: #0045b9;
     text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #002669,
         0px 4px 4px #002c78,
         0px 3px 3px #002e7a,
         0px 2px 2px #00338a,
         0px 1px 1px #00348b;
}  a:visited {
     background-color: #003794;
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.9em;
     color: #0045b9;
     text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #002669,
         0px 4px 4px #002c78,
         0px 3px 3px #002e7a,
         0px 2px 2px #00338a,
         0px 1px 1px #00348b;
} a:hover {
     background-color: #003794;
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.9em;
     color: #003794;
     text-decoration: none;
} @media all and (max-width: 50em) {
     #button {
         font-size: 1.5em;
     }
} @media all and (max-width: 40.625em) {
     #button {
         font-size: 1.25em;
     }
} @media all and (max-width: 35em) {
     #button {
         font-size: 1em;
     }
}
```

Comment: Take the font-size attribute out of the :hover and :visited selectors.  That way the font-size for the #button will style the link.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything. The font size was styling the link beforehand.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `a:hover` to `#button:hover`. Due to [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) the `a` rules aren't being applied because the `#button` selector is more specific.

Your CSS could also be simplified to:

```
#button {
      background-color: #003794;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.9em;
      color: #0045b9;
      text-decoration: none;
          text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #002669,
          0px 4px 4px #002c78,
          0px 3px 3px #002e7a,
          0px 2px 2px #00338a,
          0px 1px 1px #00348b;
 }  

 #button:visited {

      color: #0045b9;

 } 

 #button:hover {

      color: #003794;

 } 

 @media all and (max-width: 50em) {
      #button {
          font-size: 1.5em;
      }
 } 
 @media all and (max-width: 40.625em) {
      #button {
          font-size: 1.25em;
      }
 } 
 @media all and (max-width: 35em) {
      #button {
          font-size: 1em;
      }
 }
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/5kFXq/).

Answer (score 0):

change #button at the top, to a. The id selector is taking precedence, that's why it doesn't change.